# java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class, failed compile-time verification on calling class

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-runtime

I need to call class data in my selectuser class
I am using it when user selects any item from spinner

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    int icon = imgid1[userspinner.getSelectedItemPosition()];
    prefs.edit().putInt("userposition", icon).commit();
    data d = new data();
    data d1 = d.Accept(userspinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
    current.setText(d1.getWeapon_pack());
}
```

It shows error on

```
data d = new data();
```

Here is Stacktrace

```
06-05 11:29:43.796 3011-3011/com.pttest.com.pockettankstips E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.pttest.com.pockettankstips, PID: 3011
                                                                          java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class com.pttest.com.pockettankstips.data because it failed compile-time verification (declaration of 'com.pttest.com.pockettankstips.data' appears in /data/app/com.pttest.com.pockettankstips-2/base.apk)
                                                                              at com.pttest.com.pockettankstips.selectuser.onItemSelected(selectuser.java:455)
                                                                              at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:897)
                                                                              at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:48)
                                                                              at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:865)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Post your `data` class. (While you wait for answer learn your naming conventions.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you, but I was getting the same error message on starting a new activity. Disabling "Instant Run" in Android Studio preferences makes this error go away.

[image: settings screen shot]